# Difference in Url provided by IIS6 and IIS7 for default document urls

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-6

I'm working on a legacy cms with a home-written url-rewrite httpmodule. The site has been running on IIS6 for years and it's now time to upgrade to IIS7.

The httpmodule hooks up to Application_BeginRequest and does it's magic. 
We don't use wildcard-routing in IIS, but we have set up a default document called main.aspx. The main.aspx does exist to make IIS route the request to the isapi.dll, thereby triggering our httpmodule. This works in iis6 and iis7 (classic mode).

We get one problem though. The difference in behaviour we're seeing:

- IIS6: browsing to `example.com/?tracking=1234` yields in our httpmodule `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` = `/main.aspx?tracker=1234`
- IIS7: browsing to `example.com/?tracking=1234` yields in our httpmodule `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` = `/?tracker=1234`

The default document is missing when running the site in IIS7.

This missing default document in the url provided from IIS causes problem for us. Does anyone know why this behaviour has changed?